# Can I Check in/Check out files directly from my sharepoint site to TFS? How?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, sharepoint-2013

Is it possible to check in /check out files to Team foundation server from share point site without going through Visual studio? Is this Integration possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's impossible. This can't be achieved for now. The ways how to add a file in source control, please refer [Adding a file to version control](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-files-server) from MSDN.